# I am trying to destroy an instantiated gameobject with destroy using a variable, but it says the variable doesnt exist. (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im somewhat new to Unity, (1 year) and I have a problem where Im trying to destroy an object but it wont allow me saying data will be lost. So I assigned a variable to instantiate, but now that im trying to destroy that It says the variable doesnt exist. Any help?

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class TreasuryAmount : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int money = 0;
    public int troopCount = 0;

    public Text oText;
    public Button oButton;
    public Text eText;

    public Transform troop;
    public GameObject gameObject;

    void Start()
    {
        Button eButton = oButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        eButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    public void TaskOnClick()
    {
        if (money <= 999)
        {
            Debug.Log("Not Enough Money!");
        }
        else if (money >= 1000)
        {

            money -= 1000;
            var troopClone = Instantiate(gameObject, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            troopCount++;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        money++;
        oText.text = money.ToString();
        eText.text = troopCount.ToString();

        if (troopCount <= 0)
        {
            troopCount = 0;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            DestroyTroop();
        }

        void DestroyTroop()
        {
            Destroy(troopClone);
            troopCount--;
        }
    }
}
```

Error is:
**Assets\TreasuryAmount.cs(56,21): error CS0103: The name 'troopClone' does not exist in the current context**

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: I saw I put DestroyTroop() in Update, i moved it and it still didnt work :/

Comment: `var troopClone = Instantiate...`  That's local to that `if` block.  You need to declare it at the class level.

Comment: Error has nothing to do with unity3d - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0103

Comment: That fixed my problem, Thank you guys!